# Remove records with empty elements from split XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a project underway where I have to split large XML documents with 20-40K records into individual XML files for document creation and processing.

I have the XSLT 2 stylesheet working to create the split records. My problem is that there are always rows with empty elements at the bottom of all the original XML files.

The processing works, but throws an error because the rows with empty nodes cannot be properly named by the stylesheet when split off. I would prefer to deliver a clean solution that removes the empty rows and that does not indicate an error condition.

Here is an example of what the XML looks like:

```
   <row>
      <elem name="Id">75839</elem>
      <elem name="VoucherCode">KqQvtQh</elem>
      <elem name="Barcode">ÌKqQvtQh'Î</elem>
   </row>
   <row>
      <elem name="Id">75840</elem>
      <elem name="VoucherCode">txFVNmi</elem>
      <elem name="Barcode">ÌtxFVNmiSÎ</elem>
   </row>
   <row>
      <elem name="Id">75841</elem>
      <elem name="VoucherCode">EbpfKEs</elem>
      <elem name="Barcode">ÌEbpfKEs@Î</elem>
   </row>
   <row>
      <elem name="Id">75642</elem>
      <elem name="VoucherCode">cmB6UrJ</elem>
      <elem name="Barcode">ÌcmB6UrJiÎ</elem>
   </row>
   <row>
      <elem name="Id">75643</elem>
      <elem name="VoucherCode">DC3nUbS</elem>
      <elem name="Barcode">ÌDC3nUbSÄÎ</elem>
   </row>
   <row>
      <elem name="Id"/>
      <elem name="VoucherCode"/>
      <elem name="Barcode"/>
   </row>
   <row>
      <elem name="Id"/>
      <elem name="VoucherCode"/>
      <elem name="Barcode"/>
   </row>
   <row>
      <elem name="Id"/>
      <elem name="VoucherCode"/>
      <elem name="Barcode"/>
   </row>
   <row>
      <elem name="Id"/>
      <elem name="VoucherCode"/>
      <elem name="Barcode"/>
    </row>
```

And here is the XSL stylesheet I am using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/row">
            <xsl:variable name="jid" select="elem[@name='Id']"/>
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat($jid,'.xml')}" method="xml">
                <root>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
                </root>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have searched the forums extensively to try to understand how to remove the empty rows, but nothing I try removes them.

I would be very appreciative if anyone can provide some guidance how to eliminate the empty rows.

Many thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, I would strongly recommend bringing the problem with the blank IDs to the attention of whoever provides your source data if you haven't already. While it is of course always possible to implement code to handle 'bad' data, it's made your job harder here, and it probably will do again in the future. The message might be ignored, but I've spent too much time debugging through obsolete code that only ever existed to cope with bad source data and ended up causing problems further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

This would work. You can optionally add conditions for the other two `elem`, if required, to check for non-null values:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/row[elem[@name = 'Id'] != '']">
        <xsl:variable name="jid" select="elem[@name='Id']"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="{concat($jid,'.xml')}" method="xml">
            <root>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
            </root>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Lingamurthy. Thanks for your reply. This worked great as well. Thanks for the help with the select syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle this a little differently than the other answers. I wouldn't use `xsl:for-each` and instead of trying to override those other rows, I wouldn't apply templates to them in the first place.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row[string(elem[@name='Id'])]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:result-document href="{concat(elem[@name='Id'],'.xml')}" method="xml">
            <root>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </root>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This way if you need to do further processing you can change the `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>`, add an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and then override whatever else you need to process.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Many thanks for that! It works brilliantly. Sorry for the delay. I've been travelling all day and am at yet another airport about to fly to the UK. I really like the idea of using a template. Thanks again.